Lyapunov function for double integrator with saturated input and saturated states
Consider the closed-loop double-integrator system
$\begin{aligned}& \dot{x}(t)=A x(t)+B \sigma(u(t)), \quad x(0)=x_0 \\& u(t)=K x(t)\end{aligned}$
$A=\left[\begin{array}{ll}0 & 1 \\0 & 0\end{array}\right], \quad B=\left[\begin{array}{l}0 \\1\end{array}\right], \quad x=\left[\begin{array}{l}x_1 \\x_2\end{array}\right], \quad K=\left[\begin{array}{ll}k_1 & k_2\end{array}\right]$
with saturated input $\sigma_i(u_i) = sat(u_i)$
Tyan and Bernstein have proposed a Lyapunov function to solve the problem of a saturated input double integrator:
$V(x)=x^{\mathrm{T}} P x+2 \int_0^{K x} \sigma(u) \mathrm{d} u$
Now I’m trying to add a saturation to both of the states.
My approach was to estimate the bounds of the states. According to H. Khalil Nonlinear Systems (p. 173f) the boundaries of the state variable can be estimated through an $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.
Therefore an upper and a lower bound of $V(x)$ has to be found:
$V(x) \geq \lambda_{min}(P)||x||_2^2 + ||\sigma(Kx)||_2^2 \geq \lambda_{min}(P)||x||_2^2 + \lambda_{min}(\beta K)||x||_2^2 \geq \lambda_{min}(P,\beta K)||x||_2^2$
$V(x) \leq \lambda_{max}(P)||x||_2^2 + ||\sigma(Kx)||_2^2 \leq \lambda_{max}(P)||x||_2^2 + \lambda_{max}(\beta K)||x||_2^2 \leq \lambda_{max}(P,\beta K)||x||_2^2$
Thus
$\alpha_1(r) = \lambda_{min}(P,\beta K)r^2$
$\alpha_2(r)= \lambda_{max}(P,\beta K)r^2$
Leading to the bound:
$b=\alpha_1^{-1}(\alpha_2(\mu))=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha_2(\mu)}{\lambda_{min}(P,\beta K)}}=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_{max}(P,\beta K)\mu^2}{\lambda_{min}(P,\beta K)}}$
However this bound does not carry much information, as for $\lambda_{min}(P,\beta K)\approx\lambda_{max}(P,\beta K)$:
$b\approx\mu$
Is there a better approach to add boundedness to the states $x$? Do I have to choose another Lyapunov function to bound the states $x$? Finally I would like to bound the states to a specific value e.g. with a saturation.

What do you mean by "add a saturation to both of the states"? Can you provide more details in the question?
